# integrate Bluesnap api with Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, payment-gateway, bluesnap

I am working with the Bluesnap payment gateway api and what I found that I have to add my IP address in sandbox of bluesnap. But how could I know what will be my IP address while I am trying to call the API From Salesforce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IP filtering can be disabled upon request. You just need to contact their support team telling them why you need it disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working for BlueSnap;

I wanted to let you know that we've just went live with our new SalesForce integration, see our documentation for more details:
https://support.bluesnap.com/docs/salesforce

Dan.